# Unable to run TensorFlow on Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, tensorflow, pyspark

I am trying to make TensorFlow work on my Spark cluster in order to make it run in parallel.
As a start, I tried to use this [demo](https://gist.github.com/tnachen/e004539cdd38e5941d0cb712d0ad3b91) as-is.

The demo works great without Spark, but when using Spark, I get the following error:

```
16/08/02 10:44:16 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: collect at   /home/hdfs/tfspark.py:294, took 1.151383 s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hdfs/tfspark.py", line 294, in <module>
    local_labelled_images = labelled_images.collect()
  File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 771, in collect
  File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError16/08/02 10:44:17 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on localhost:45020 in memory (size: 6.4 KB, free: 419.5 MB)
16/08/02 10:44:17 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 2
: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 422, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 118, in __getattr__
    _module = self._resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 118, in __getattr__
    _module = self._resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 118, in __getattr__
    _module = self._resolve()
.
.
.
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I get the same error when I use pyspark or when I use spark-submit directly.

I tried to increase the recursion limit to 50000 (even though it is probably not the root-cause), but it didn't help.

Since the error is with the ***six*** package, I thought that python 3 may fix it, but I didn't try it yet since it may require adjustments in our production environment (would be better if we can avoid it).

Should python 3 work better with pyspark? (I know it works well with TensorFlow)

Any idea of how to make it work with python 2?

I am running TensorFlow 0.9.0 Spark 1.6.1 in HortonWorks cluster on RHEL 7.2 with python 2.7.5.

Thanks

#### Update:

Tried it with python 3.5 - getting the same exception. So apparently upgrading to python 3 is not a possible workaround.

Comment: Do you know how big would be your graph?

Comment: Let's say the graph would be pretty basic, e.g. a few layers of LSTM. However, I don't think the 'size of the graph' has something to do with the problem, because as you can see from the exception I got, the error occurs when I call the _collect_ method and is originated from pyspark.

Comment: Humm that's true. I didn't realised that. I was thinking about graph path of really large graph that I already had one issue like that. It was too many edges to go... And I got an error similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally realised that the root-cause is the six module itself - it has some compatibility issues with spark, and whenever it is loaded there are problems.

Therefore, to solve the issue I searched for all the usages of the ***six*** package in the demo, and replaced them with an equivalent module from python 2 (for example, *six.moves.urllib.response* simply became *urllib2*). When all the occurrences of six are removed, the demo runs perfectly on Spark.